# JavaScript: Exception thrown in parent window occurs in child window

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I came across a problem that made me confused. We all know that a couple of browsers window(tabs) which have the same origin can share JavaScript resources.

So, I made a parent window open a child window via `window.open`. The child window calls a global function in parent window via `window.opener.functionName`. Take a look at two snippets below:

**parent.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Parent</h1>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

function sayHi(child) {
    console.log("Before throwing an error..");
    throw new Error('Some error');
}

window.open('child.html')

</script>
</html>
```

**child.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Child</h1>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.opener.sayHi(window);

</script>
</html>
```

The problem is: You can find the `console.log` result in `parent.html` window, but that exception thrown in parent window will weirdly occur in `child.html` window. It makes me confused, I need that exception in parent window because of BDD Test. How can I make it happen?

Sorry for my poor English, feel free to correct my grammar mistakes.

========================Update======================

I have found a solution to this question, using HTML5 feature `postMessage`. But I am still curious why it happen. What makes the exception escape from parent window to child window? Any inspiration is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the solution by myself. The solution is easy: In the child window, informs parent window to call the function via `postMessage`. It works as I want it to. I caught the exception in parent window.